# Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 won't install Version 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

```
sudo apt install qgis
```

installs 2.8 (on 16.04) or 2.18 (on 18.04), but I would like to install version 3 (especially the 3.10 **ltr**) so I've tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr
```

which works as at the bottom of `/etc/apt/sources.list` there is:

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr xenial main
# deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr xenial main
```

But this doesn't change what's installed - apparently that repository can't be used - I'm told by apt update:

```
Get:16 https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr buster InRelease [3,687 B]
rr:16 https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr buster InRelease                       
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51F523511C7028C3
Reading package lists... Done                        
W: GPG error: https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 51F523511C7028C3
E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

I'm also told:

```
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So apparently I need a key to securely acquire 3.10 from the ltr repository

Following the debian ubuntu instructions, I entered:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key
51F523511C7028C3
```

and while that stopped update complaints, I still can't install qgis because it complains about broken packages.

---

Set up a 16.04 image and did `sudo apt update` then `upgrade` then and `autoremove`.

Following the suggestion from [Eric Gagné](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/360283/65370), I added the `update` command as well.

I tried 3 different of these

#### First

By just adding `update`:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 51F523511C7028C3
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install qgis
$ qgis &
```

It runs but it's version 2.18.

#### Second

I added `$ sudo apt upgrade` after the `update` command.
It runs but it's also version 2.18.

#### Third

I changed to remove the `ltr` so as to try to get `3.12`

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository https://qgis.org/ubuntu
```

I didn't use `$ sudo apt upgrade` this time.
It runs but it's version 2.18.

So adding the extra `update` lets it run - but I don't get version 3???

Comment: You need to run `apt-get update` after adding the GPG key. And only then to actually install your software. [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/15272/571173). If you still have error messages, please paste them by editing your post.

Comment: What's the result of: `sudo apt-cache policy qgis`? Did you also *properly* removed QGIS 2.18?

Comment: After receiving the suggestion I ran apt update after the key and it installed. That was on a new virtual machine. But earlier when it kept on installing 2.18, I had both removed it with a succession of apt-get remove, autoremove and autoremove --purge and started fresh with a new virtual machine - neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run sudo apt update after adding the repository ?

For Ubuntu 18.04 try this.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 51F523511C7028C3
```

In /etc/apt/sources make sure you have

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr/ bionic main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu-ltr/ bionic main
```

Note the bionic for 18.04, not xenial and the deb-src line is not commented out.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass qgis-provider-grass qgis-providers qgis-server
```

That works on Linux Mint 19,3, should work just the same on Unbuntu 18.04

Comment: Following the suggestion from @EricGagne I used 18.04, and $ sudo add-apt-repository https://qgis.org/ubuntu  Then at the end of /etc/apt/sources  it was bionic, but didn't have the -ltr and the deb-src line was commented out. But I ran sudo apt update, the sudo apt install qgis   And then  qgis  ran and it was Version QGOS 3.12.2-Cucuresti    I don't know what's going on - why I couldn't get 3.10 - but I can work with this!